# c# How to detect if an external application has popped up a window?

Tags: c#

I keep getting multiple verification prompt from a 3rd party application where on many instances I have to select the prompt window, type my password and click on Ok. I thought of writing a simple application in WHITE framework which can capture the window, enter my password and deliver a click automatically.

I need to detect whenever a new window has popped up in Windows environment. I don't want to use either a timer or a loop. Can I get an event when ever a new window appears (registers) ?

-- Regards
Akshay Mishra

Comment: Man i hope someone will write this for you ,but i don't think so ,try to display some Code than we will help you !!

Comment: Hi Cody
I have been coding since more than last 5 yrs. Novices code and think - I think and code. Coding is not that difficult as is to think - what to.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outside of managed code you could use global WindowHooks, however this involves injecting a DLL into another process space. 
This is not easily done with managed DLLs (read: assemblies).  (It can be done, see [here](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/how-to-inject-a-managed-assembly-dll))

I wrote an [article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/global_hook_cbt.aspx) a while ago on how to create a sort of managed global hook for WM_CREATE and WM_DESTROY messages.
It includes full source code and it probably has what you need. Your application will need administrator privileges for this!

Comment: Hi yas4891
Thanks for the help. Looks like I got a hint. 
Thanks a lot :)